# How to configure Elasticsearch Index Lifecycle Management (ILM) in eck-operator

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, cloud, kibana

I use eck-operator (with eck-operator-crd) from official elastic repository
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/eck-operator
Kibana and Elasticsearch manifests are deploying and working fine.
My question is how to configure additional features like:
Index Lifecycle Policy, Kibana Data View, New Templates, Data Streams, Dashboards etc.?
I saw few operators with kind of manifests but nothing from mentioned above.
Thanks for any remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do that via config maps. We store the index templates and index life cycle policies as json format. Also an execution script is a part of config map which pushes the index templates and ilm policies to elasticsearch via POST. Since everything is inside the volume now, we then create a cron job to execute this script.

For example this is the index template
all-indices.json:

```
{
    "index_patterns": ["abc*"],
    "priority": 300,
    "composed_of": ["template1", "template2"], 
    "version": 3
}
```

execution-script.sh

```
 curl -XPUT "http://some_url:9200/_index_template/all-indices" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @/etc/elasticsearch-templates/all-indices.json
```

We create these config map from terraform.

kibana.yaml

```
...
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        volumeMounts:
        - name: elasticsearch-templates
          mountPath: /etc/elasticsearch-templates
          readOnly: true
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 15 && sh /etc/elasticsearch-templates/execution-script.sh"]
      volumes:
        - name: elasticsearch-templates
          configMap:
            name: ilm-and-index-templates
```

Then the cron job executes the script

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: script-execution
spec:
  schedule: "0 5 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: script-execution
            image: alpine/curl:latest
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - sh /etc/elasticsearch-templates/execution-script.sh
            volumeMounts:
            - name: elasticsearch-templates
              mountPath: /etc/elasticsearch-templates
              readOnly: true
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
            - name: elasticsearch-templates
              configMap:
                name: ilm-and-index-templates
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did it almost in same way. I use K8S Job instead of CronJob. Only what I need is to create bash loop to wait until elasticsearch is available and curl can put data.